# Confusing information on Steam regarding version of Settlers 7

Tags: steam

The page in the steam store for [Settlers 7 Deluxe Gold Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/901249) says it includes all the DLC content

> The Deluxe Gold Edition includes the original game fully patched and **complete DLC content**, plus free additional content:
>
> - 13 exclusive maps: 6 multiplayer maps and 7 single player campaigns.
> - A dozen new buildings. Including the Crypt, Order of Knights, Infernal mine.
> - Over 30 new locations. Including Field of Mandrake, Treasure Island, Pilgrimage site.
> - Castle forge elements allowing players to make their cities unique and customize their castles: 1 gate, 2 windows, 1 bay, 1 balcony and 1 gargoyle.

However, a little under that text there's a link to purchase the DLC content

[image: Settlers 7 purchase information screenshot]

So, does the game include the DLC or not? Is it referring to another DLC?
Also, I was unable to find "the original game" (the one that's not the Deluxe Gold Edition) in the store.

Comment: I think this could be better answered by the Steam Support Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found detailed information on the [official page](http://thesettlers.uk.ubi.com/the-settlers-7/news/page-1/#12574)

> The **Settlers 7: Paths to a Kingdom Gold Edition** contains:
>
>   Settlers 7: Paths to a Kingdom
>   full game
> - Settlers 7: DLC Pack 1
>   - Three additional challenging multiplayer maps ("*Battle of Tanholm"*; "*Tempest Taiga"*; "*Fiery Chasm"*)
>
> - Settlers 7: DLC Pack 2
>   - Three additional 4-player-Maps ("*Whitewater Falls"*; "*Twin Peaks"*; "*Grassland Mesa"*) for Skirmish, Multiplayer & Empire Mode.
>   - Additional Event Location ("*Tower of Tandria"*)
>   - Additional Victory Point ("*Pacifist*"; "*Economist*"; *Ascetic*")
>   - Additional Ecobuilding ("*Order of Knights*"; "*Infernal Mines*")
>
> - Settlers 7: DLC Pack 3
>   - A Campaign Expansion ("*Rise of the Rebellion"*) with 5 additional Campaign-Maps
>   - A Scenario Expansion ("Shadow Over Tandria") with 2 additional gigantic Scenario-Maps

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that the DLC is just there for users who originally bought the "non-deluxe" game without all the DLC.  I've seen Steam retire the original versions of games before, and just keep the special editions.

Comment: That makes sense, confirmation would be nice